# Julia - How to find the specific data in the Julia DataFrame by conditions and change it?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame that has the following structure, for example:

```
show(q)
```

```
2×5 DataFrame
 Row │ state   left     right    up       down    
     │ Any     Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ (1, 1)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
   2 │ (2, 2)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

where I use the column `state` as an index column that takes tuples as indexes. I want to access the data using the index such as `q[q.state .== (1,1), 'down']`, how can I do that?

Furthermore, when I use this command `q[q.state .== (1,1), :]` to access the row of the corresponding state, it returns me an empty DataFrame:

```
0×5 DataFrame
 Row │ state  left     right    up       down    
     │ Any    Float64  Float64  Float64  Float64
─────┴───────────────────────────────────────────
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the mistake you make is when you write `q.state .== (1,1)`, as it produces:

```
julia> q.state .== (1,1)
2-element BitVector:
 0
 0
```

because `(1,1)` is broadcasted over.

You need to write:

```
julia> q.state .== Ref((1,1))
2-element BitVector:
 1
 0
```

to treat `(1,1)` as scalar.

Now you have:

```
julia> q[q.state .== Ref((1,1)), :]
1×5 DataFrame
 Row │ state   left  right  up   down
     │ Any     Any   Any    Any  Any
─────┼────────────────────────────────
   1 │ (1, 1)  0.0   0.0    0.0  0.0
```

If you want to access a single cell of a data frame, with lookup write:

```
julia> q[findfirst(==((1,1)), q.state), :down]
0.0
```

or if you are more prudent (and make sure you have only one match):

```
julia> q[only(findall(==((1,1)), q.state)), :down]
0.0
```